# Strange query generated in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Below is my code where I am calling three methods from three models to retrieve counts as below.

```
    $this->load->model('orders_model');
    $order_count = $this->orders_model->count_orders(array("executive_id" => $this->id));

    $this->load->model('activities_model');
    $activity_count = $this->activities_model->count_activities(array("users_id" => $this->id));

    $this->load->model('leads_model');
    $leads_count = $this->leads_model->count_leads(array("users_id" => $this->id));
```

And this is the query I am getting:

> SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` FROM `orders`, `activities`, `leads` WHERE `executive_id` = '5' AND `users_id` = '5' AND `users_id` = '5'

which leads to a database error

[image: screenshot of error]

Why is this happening?

Orders_model

```
class Orders_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_orders($order_id = FALSE) {
        if ($order_id === FALSE) {
            $query = $this->db->get('orders');
            return $query->result();
        }
        $this->db->where('id', $order_id);
        $query = $this->db->get('orders');
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function add_order($order_data = FALSE) {
        if (!$order_data === FALSE) {
            if (is_array($order_data)) {
                return $this->db->insert('orders', $order_data);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function update_order($order_update_data = FALSE, $order_update_condition = FALSE) {
        if (!($order_update_data === FALSE && $order_update_condition === FALSE)) {
            if (is_array($order_update_data) && is_array($order_update_condition)) {
                return $this->db->update('orders', $order_update_data, $order_update_condition);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function get_custom_orders($order_custom_condition = FALSE) {
        if (!$order_custom_condition === FALSE) {
            if (is_array($order_custom_condition)) {
                #echo "Yes a parameter is passed which is also an array";
                $this->db->where($order_custom_condition);
                $query = $this->db->get('orders');
                return $query->result();
            }
        }
    }

    public function get_last_ref_id() {
        $query = $this->db->query('select sprx_ref_id from orders where id in (select max(id) from orders)');
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            return $row->sprx_ref_id;
        }
    }

    public function fetch_orders($limit, $start, $order_custom_condition) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
        $this->db->where($order_custom_condition);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function count_orders($order_custom_condition) {
        $this->db->where($order_custom_condition);
        return $this->db->count_all_results('orders', FALSE);
    }

}
```

Activities_model

```
class Activities_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_activities($activity_id = FALSE) {

        if ($activity_id === FALSE) {
            $query = $this->db->get('activities');
            return $query->result();
        }
        $this->db->where('id', $activity_id);
        #$this->db->order_by('id','ASC');
        $query = $this->db->get('activities');
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function add_activity($activity_data = FALSE) {
        if (!$activity_data === FALSE) {
            if (is_array($activity_data)) {
                return $this->db->insert('activities', $activity_data);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function update_activity($activity_update_data = FALSE, $activity_update_condition = FALSE) {
        if (!($activity_update_data === FALSE && $activity_update_condition)) {
            if (is_array($activity_update_data) && is_array($activity_update_condition)) {
                return $this->db->update('activities', $activity_update_data, $activity_update_condition);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function get_custom_activities($activity_custom_condition = FALSE) {
        if (!$activity_custom_condition === FALSE) {
            if (is_array($activity_custom_condition)) {
                #echo "Yes a parameter is passed which is also an array";
                $this->db->where($activity_custom_condition);
                $query = $this->db->get('activities');
                return $query->result();
            }
        }
    }

    public function fetch_activities($limit, $start, $custom_condition) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
        $this->db->where($custom_condition);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function count_activities($custom_condition) {
        $this->db->where($custom_condition);
        return $this->db->count_all_results('activities', FALSE);
    }

}
```

Leads_model

```
class Leads_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_leads($lead_id = FALSE) {
        if ($lead_id === FALSE) {
            $query = $this->db->get('leads');
            return $query->result();
        }
        $this->db->where('id', $lead_id);
        $query = $this->db->get('leads');
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function add_lead($lead_data = FALSE) {
        if (!$lead_data === FALSE) {
            if (is_array($lead_data)) {
                return $this->db->insert('leads', $lead_data);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function update_lead($lead_update_data = FALSE, $lead_update_condition = FALSE) {
        if (!($lead_update_data === FALSE && $lead_update_condition)) {
            if (is_array($lead_update_data) && is_array($lead_update_condition)) {
                return $this->db->update('leads', $lead_update_data, $lead_update_condition);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function get_custom_leads($lead_custom_condition = FALSE) {
        if (!$lead_custom_condition === FALSE) {
            if (is_array($lead_custom_condition)) {
                #echo "Yes a parameter is passed which is also an array";
                $this->db->where($lead_custom_condition);
                $query = $this->db->get('leads');
                return $query->result();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function fetch_leads($limit, $start, $lead_custom_condition) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
        $this->db->where($lead_custom_condition);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function count_leads($lead_custom_condition) {
        $this->db->where($lead_custom_condition);
        return $this->db->count_all_results('leads', FALSE);

    }

}
```

Comment: show the model code

Comment: Ok just wait a minute

Comment: Probably you have `users_id` in more than one table (orders, activities, leads)

Comment: Yes In leads and activities but in orders table it has name executive_id

Comment: Did you mean to get the record count of the 3 combined tables? Because that error message seems to be only a symptom to me. The way I read your code is that the `count_*()` methods should return the count from their respective tables only.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, you are surprised why the query builder uses additional parameter from the previous query.

> You've to reset your Query according to [docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=count_all_results#CI_DB_query_builder::count_all_results)

which means all your "count_" functions should be like

```
public function count_leads($lead_custom_condition) {
    $this->db->where($lead_custom_condition);
    return $this->db->count_all_results('leads');

}
```

obviously you did set the false flag on purpose - but i'm not sure why ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the error message is only a symptom, not the actual cause of the issue

. The way I read your code is that the `count_*()` methods in each of the 3 models should return the count from their respective tables only.

However, the way you wrote your count functions results in the query builder **adding** the tables and conditions to the overall query, not executing them just on the single tables

```
$this->db->where($custom_condition); <-- this adds a new where condition using "and" operator
return $this->db->count_all_results('activities', FALSE); <-- just adds another table without resetting the others
```

I would add a `$this->db->reset_query();` line as the 1st line in each of the 3 `count_*()` methods to force the query builder to start from scratch.

Comment: Problem solved by removing the FALSE flag in count_all_results(); ,

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to using the second argument to `$this->db->count_all_results()`. When you set the second argument to FALSE then `$this->db` will not clear any `select` statements from its cache. Then each successive call to `count_all_results()` will include the table from any prior call to the function. The solution is simple - don't use the second parameter.

Change

```
return $this->db->count_all_results('activities', FALSE);
```

to

```
return $this->db->count_all_results('activities');
```

Not related to your problem but something that will improve your code is changing this

```
public function get_orders($order_id = FALSE) {
    if ($order_id === FALSE) {
        $query = $this->db->get('orders');
        return $query->result();
    }
    $this->db->where('id', $order_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('orders');
    return $query->result();
}
```

to

```
public function get_orders($order_id = NULL) {
    if (!empty($order_id)) 
    {
       $this->db->where('id', $order_id);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get('orders');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Changing the argument default to NULL and using `!empty($order_id)` helps because it protects against and empty string or empty array being given as the argument. (Ready about `empty()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).)

This new logic also keeps the code DRY - your not repeating the two line of code to `get` and `return` results.

Many of your other model functions could be cleaner too. For instance

```
public function add_order($order_data = FALSE) {
    if (!$order_data === FALSE) {
        if (is_array($order_data)) {
            return $this->db->insert('orders', $order_data);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

would be cleaner written like this

```
public function add_order($order_data = NULL) {
    if (!empty($order_data) && is_array($order_data)) 
    {
       return $this->db->insert('orders', $order_data);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Sorry for nitpicking your code - I couldn't help myself.